# How to calculate the loss if the value is equal to 0 in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to calculate the loss if the value is equal to 0 in Google Sheets, for example in the screenshot I attached, if I don't get any sales, so I want to see -$10 in Profit Per Unit cell.

Any solution and tricks to get this function works.

[image: Here's an example]

Comment: `=IF(C3=0,-A3,A3/C3)`?... though I'm not sure this actually makes economic sense.

Comment: @BigBen it works! Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Hi @BigBen, Do you know how to make the field empty until I put values in A and C cells?
https://imgur.com/a/V2Ny6iQ

Comment: `=IF(OR(A3="",C3=""),"",IF(C3=0,-A3,A3/C3))`

Comment: Thank you @BigBen for your help, it's working well

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

use in row 2:

```
=INDEX(IF((A2:A="")+(C2:C=""),,IF(C2:C*1=0, -A2:A, A2:A/C2:C)))
```